# Defining instances of a third-party typeclass, implicit not found but explicit works fine

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

I'm working with [Slick's `GetResult` typeclass](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/GetResult.fm) and wanted to use Shapeless to derive instances of `GetResult[Option[(A, B, C...)]]`

**What I want:**

Given an implicit `GetResult[Option[A]], GetResult[Option[B]], ...`,
implicitly generate a `GetResult[Option[(A, B, ...)]]`

**What I tried**

```
trait CanGetOption[T] {
    def getOption: GetResult[Option[T]]
}
object CanGetOption {
    // convenience implicit resolver
    def apply[T](implicit canGetOption: CanGetOption[T]): CanGetOption[T] = canGetOption

    // base case: HNil
    implicit val getHNilOption: CanGetOption[HNil] = from(GetResult { _ => Some(HNil) })

    // recursion case: H :: Tail
    implicit def getHConsOption[H, Tail <: HList](
        implicit getHeadOption: GetResult[Option[H]], 
        canGetTailOption: CanGetOption[Tail]
    ): CanGetOption[H :: Tail] = from(GetResult[Option[H :: Tail]] { r =>
        val headOpt = getHeadOption(r)
        val tailOpt = canGetTailOption.getOption(r)
        for(head <- headOpt; tail <- tailOpt) yield head :: tail
    })

    // generic case: A, given a A <-> Repr conversion
    // I also tried moving this into a "LowPriorityImplicits" thing, just in case
    implicit def getGenericOption[A, Repr <: HList](
        implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, Repr], 
        getReprOpt: CanGetOption[Repr]
    ): CanGetOption[A] = from(GetResult { r =>
        val reprOpt = getReprOpt.getOption(r)
        reprOpt.map(gen.from)
    })
}

implicit def resolveOptionGetter[T: CanGetOption]: GetResult[Option[T]] = 
    CanGetOption[T].getOption
```

**Problem:**

When I've imported the above, the `resolveOptionGetter` doesn't seem to be considered when searching for implicits:

```
scala> implicitly[GetResult[Option[(Int, Int)]]]
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[Option[(Int, Int)]]
       implicitly[GetResult[Option[(Int, Int)]]]
             ^

scala> resolveOptionGetter[(Int, Int)]
res1: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[Option[(Int, Int)]] = <function1>
```

Why can't the compiler find `resolveOptionGetter` in the implicit search? What can I do to help it?

Comment: Where exactly is `resolveOptionGetter` defined? In your example it's not inside any object or class which is illegal.

Comment: @ghik It was all in a container element, and I imported that all in my REPL session. I omitted it from the question to avoid over-indenting the already-long lines in it.

Comment: @Dylan I guess I finally found solution. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `slick.jdbc.GetResult` is covariant. If it were invariant, types would be inferred correctly and implicits would be resolved.

A workaround is hiding covariant `slick.jdbc.GetResult` with custom invariant type alias `GetResult`. Remove import `slick.jdbc.GetResult` and write in your source file

```
type GetResult[T] = slick.jdbc.GetResult[T]

object GetResult {
  def apply[T](implicit f: PositionedResult => T): GetResult[T] = slick.jdbc.GetResult.apply
}
```

Now `implicitly[GetResult[Option[(Int, Int)]]]` compiles. Tested in Scala 2.12.7 + Shapeless 2.3.3 + Slick 3.2.3.

Variance often makes troubles for implicit resolution:

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10099

https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/issues/1292

[Implicit resolution with covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426378/implicit-resolution-with-covariance)

Comment: I'm accepting your updated answer since it addresses what I asked. Unfortunately it doesn't help with my actual usage, which is to construct instances of `StaticQuery[R]`, where `R` belongs to the `GetResult` typeclass. Having the invariant version of GetResult imported instead of the main one doesn't seem to help with that use case. I still have to say `implicit val getter = resolveOptionGetter[(Int, Int)]` before I can call `StaticQuery[Option[(Int, Int)]]` :(

Comment: You can remove import `slick.jdbc.StaticQuery` as well as `slick.jdbc.GetResult` and write `object StaticQuery {
    def apply[R: GetResult]: StaticQuery[Unit, R] = slick.jdbc.StaticQuery.apply
  }`. Then `StaticQuery[Option[(Int, Int)]]` compiles in Scala 2.12.7 + Shapeless 2.3.3 + Slick **2.1.0**.